# Preventing the other divs from moving on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a div which I want to move on hover. However, everything below this div also moves. I only want the div class="plantools" to move on hover and not everything else underneath it. How do I stop this from happening. Please see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WKF3z/).

HTML:

```
<div id="home-plantools-col">
 <div class="plantools">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="homemidcontent">
 <div id="home-dir-left">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home-plantools-col {
width:20%;
padding:5px;
}

.plantools {
background: red;
-webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}

.plantools:hover {
margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally think it is far easier to use

```
.plantools {
    background: red;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.plantools:hover {
    top:-10px;
}
```

I used `ease-in-out` just because I like it better, but you can still use `ease-out`

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WKF3z/7/)

Comment: Great..this worked for me more because i wanted the hover effect to be smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translateY) instead of `margin`

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/WKF3z/6/)

```
.plantools {
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
.plantools:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

---

- Notice that using `transform` holds some [browser support issues](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), but so does using [`transitions`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) and you're already using it.

Comment: thanks..but the transitions effect with transform doesn't seem to be that smooth as per the fiddle?

Comment: It happens because when it goes up you're not hovering it anymore. It will happen in any solution, unless you start working with different containers etc.

Answer (score 0):

A nasty dirty way to do it,if you know the heigth it will take, is by using a wrap div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="home-plantools-col">
    <div class="plantools">
        <p>content</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and set the wrap's height to something fixed:

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WKF3z/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add "position:relative" to .plantools and change "margin-top:-10px" by "top:-10px" in .plantools:hover.

This way, the element will be moved up but will keep the same position in the flow.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3uLeF/)

Here is the updated css :

```
#home-plantools-col {
width:20%;
padding:5px;
}
.plantools {  
position:relative;
background: red;
-webkit-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: margin 0.2s ease-out;
}
.plantools:hover {
top: -10px;
}
```